# Why parenthesis are necessary for typecasting in C?

Tags: c

In C, you can typecast like this:

```
double d = 1.008;   
int i = (int)d;
```

Why was parenthesis made compulsory for typecasting? Is it because of Order of precedence? What was C's creators' thought process and logic behind this?

I am curious as to why compiler can disambiguate many other things but with typecasting, parenthesis are enforced.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking, why is the syntax of explicit conversion not this: `int i = int d`?

Comment: Because `int d;` is a variable definition/declaration and `(int)d;` is a statement (quite useless, but still useful in some cases such as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658582/is-volatile-t0x1234-guaranteed-to-translate-into-read-instruction).

Comment: @ladman That is completely valid C++ also. Yes not idiomatic, but valid. So your comment adds no value and is simply snarky.

Comment: Requiring explicit casting (via whatever syntax) can help avoid subtle programming errors, such as an unexpected loss of data (or overflow) in this case. As for why that is the syntax, might as well ask the designers of SQL why the syntax is “CAST(.. AS ..)” there or why [] is used for array indexing or..

Comment: @user2864740 Are you saying an attempt in error-avoidance, resulted in creation of language syntax?

Comment: @eerorika Yes. Essentially, I am curious as to why compiler can disambiguate many other things but with typecasting, parenthesis are enforced.

Comment: @ruohola It's valid C++ inasmuch as it's valid C, just as Objective-C has support for C as well. Should we talk about C/C++/Objective-C as a language because they all support C? This is a C problem. It was a syntax decision C made that C++ inherited. It's not C++-specific.

Answer (score 6):

```
int main()
{
    char c;
    (int)c; // int c; if no parentheses were needed
}
```

This is perfectly valid C. Now imagine that parentheses were not needed, then the cast could be interpreted a declaration as well as a cast.

Answer (score 6):

Let us pretend that they weren't required. Look at this:

```
int*d
```

Is this conversion to `int`, and the unary operator `*` applied to `d`, or is this conversion to `int*`?

How about this:

```
unsigned int 4.2
```

Is that conversion of 4.2 to `int` and then conversion to `unsigned`? Or is it conversion of 4.2 to `unsigned int`?

Ultimately, it is a design choice how ambiguities are resolved. One approach is to apply "maximal munch", another is to specify that all ambiguities are ill-formed, and the chosen approach in this case was to specify the syntax so that there can be no ambiguity.

Comment: I am not sure if this argument is really valid. If the syntax is ambiguous, then it would suffice to use parentheses when it is necessary. For example, `i+++1` is parsed as `(i++) + 1`. The same could be done here, without parentheses it is a declaration and with parentheses it is a cast. But this doesn't mean, that parentheses have to be mandatory always for a cast. Same for the answer of @Eraklon

Comment: @Ctx Fair enough. I suppose this is a choice that was made by the designers of C.

Comment: @Ctx I do think that your example is wrong in the sense it is not ambigous. The only way to interpret `i+++1` is `(i++) + 1)` since you cannot do `++1`, so it does not invalidate our statements.

Comment: @Eraklon Fair enough ;) Let's take `i+++j` then ;)

Comment: @Ctx now this a good example, but still here the order of the evaulation would decide its meaning. Its just depends on that I believe, while on the case if no parantheses cast no matter what order you evaluate it just can't be determined what is the meaning of it.

Comment: @Eraklon I do not really dispute the answers (indeed I voted you both up), but I just want to emphasize, that this isn't a _strictly logical_ requirement, because the standard _could_ require parentheses only in situations, where the "wrong" (unintended) choice would be made by the parser. The answers read a bit like "there is no choice", when there indeed is one.

Comment: @Eraklon: Order of evaluation is irrelevant in `i+++j`; it comes after parsing into tokens. Operator precedence is also irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, sorry I also include that on my mind on the term of "order of evalution" sorry. What was I thinking is that it isn't ambigous for the compiler only for the programmer at best. So I meant the ambigouity in my answer also as a compiler perspective.

Comment: @Ctx "The answers read a bit like "there is no choice", when there indeed is one". Hmm you are right. I rephrased it. Thanks.

Comment: @Eraklon Yes, but `1+++j` is not `1 + (++j)`, it is `(1++) + j`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I get your point and very good call. It seems what always happen that `x+++y` will result in `(x++)+y` regardless if `x` or `y` is constant or not. But this is also deterministic from the compiler perspective nonetheless. I wonder if this actually the standard way to handle this or may depend on the compiler implementation.

Comment: @Eraklon It's the standard way. The preprocessor is greedy and will always try to create the biggest token first.

Comment: I had this feeling that this is the case, but was not sure. Thanks for the enlightenment.