# A function to print out the name of a variable in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a function that takes in a variable and print out it name

It'd look something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_name(int a);

int main()
{
  int a_random_name;
  print_name(a_random_name);

  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
a_random_name
```

How would i be able to do this in c ?

Comment: Sooo `printf("a_name\n")`?

Comment: C doesn't provide any introspection mechanisms like this.

Comment: I think what op wants is rather something like `#define print_name(var) printf("%s\n",#var)`. I'd be glad to detail the answer if the question is reopened :)

Comment: @Barmar I think it does, using macros (as per my previous comment)

Comment: What is the point of it?

Comment: @UlysseBN you'd probably want to verify that the variable exists too, so I think `#define print_name(var) ((var), printf("%s\n",#var))` would be better.

Comment: @EugeneSh. debugging, or meta-programming. Just use your imagination! (I've used it to prefix my methods with a namespace for instance)

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 `(var)`  might have a side effect, especially if it is `volatile` (see related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658582/is-volatile-t0x1234-guaranteed-to-translate-into-read-instruction)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why would I want to print *anything?* ;-) More seriously, there is `__FILE__`,`__LINE__`  and `__FUNCTION__`; we'd conceivably wish for a "`__VAR__`".

Comment: Ok, ok, I am convinced ;)

Comment: @UlysseBN One thing with the macro, good or bad, is that it can print a lot more than variables.

Comment: Switch to C#. C requires different way of thinking.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Could `sizeof (var)` instead of `(var)` avoid those side-effects?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 at least the compiler is less whining about expression result unused ! (changing my answer)

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Yeah, will do. If you don't care about compliance with SEI CERT (https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP44-C.+Do+not+rely+on+side+effects+in+operands+to+sizeof%2C+_Alignof%2C+or+_Generic). I saw Coverity with the SEI CERT checker is complaining about `sizeof <volatile>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you cannot use a function to do so, but a macro:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define print_name(x) (sizeof (x), printf("%s\n", #x))

void foo() {}

int main()
{
    int a_random_name;
    print_name(a_random_name);
    print_name(foo);

    return 0;
}
// Prints:
// a_random_name
// foo
```

Note that the `(sizeof (x),`  part of the macro is here to make sure that the variable exists.

More information on macros manipulation:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html

C11 macros specifications:

- [http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.2)

Comment: Likely they are downvoting an answer to a question they feel should not get an answer. It is a silly reason to downvote, but people are free to downvote for any reason.

Comment: When I originally said this wasn't possible, I was assuming this was not the only thing that the function was supposed to do. I.e. it performs a calculation, so it needed to be a function. But in that case, I guess you could use a wrapper macro that expands into a call to the function that passes the string argument.

Comment: @SteveSummit How about these who *know* a thing to be impossible? ;)

Comment: I'm glad the question was reopened just for the discussions it led to :)

Comment: The only weakness of the approach is that it accepts any expression for `var`, not just identifiers. I would modify the answer to create a dummy declaration instead using the `var`.

Comment: changed for `x`

Comment: Isn't it the case that the actual answer is "No, this isn't possible _in C_, but you can use a GCC-specific macro that accomplishes the same thing"?

Comment: @Yun It is not GCC specific, it is using only standard C preprocessor functionality

Comment: @EugeneSh. So this is part of the official C-specifications?

Comment: @Yun Yes it is. See http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.2

Comment: Stringification is standard C, but `sizeof` applied to a function is not; it is [a GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith).  So `print_name(a_random_name)` is fine for a standard C compiler, but `print_name(foo)` would fail because of the `sizeof(foo)`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. and NateEldredge Interesting, thank you!

Comment: @NateEldredge Perhaps `sizeof (&x)` will fix it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. feel free to edit the answer with a reference :)